# Question regarding iOs Developer Program

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Greetings to all of you...

Thanks for stopping by...

Here me having one clarification regarding "Managing In App Purchases" in iTunes Connect Portal.

I have iOs Developer Program membership for which i paid $99.

when i log in to the iTunes Connect Portal, there is no "Manage In App Purchases" module.

It is not being shown to me really....

What membership i need for having "Manage In App Purchases" module to be visible.....

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, I also have the $99 subscription, but I have the module in my iTunes connect screen.

Are all your contracts (for paid apps) approved? Maybe that is not taken care of fully?

Comment: thanks for the reply...can you pls help how to have Paid Application contract

Comment: Look for "Contracts, tax and banking" on the main iTunes connect screen.

Comment: Hi..do we need to pay for having paid application contract?

Comment: @barbgal no, you don't have to pay extra, just fill in some information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an application? You need to have an app in the "Manage Your Applications" section before you can add an In App Purchase.

Also, it used to be the case that you had to submit a binary and reject it before you could add IAP to that app. (I hope that's fixed now since it's both confusing and lame!)

Comment: This has nothing to do with code. They are all configuration options in iTunes Connect.

Comment: no..what i am asking is if i get product information on my phone means i can be sure that all the configurations are correct...can you pls provide me some code check that product information

Comment: There's no way to do it programatically. If it didn't work you still wouldn't know which part of your configuration was incorrect.